# GTest PrintTo overloading with template

Tags: c++, googletest

I have some JSON serialization functions which I want to be used for pretty-printing in unit tests using google test library

```
namespace utils 
{
std::string ToJson(app::Foo v){return "foo";};
std::string ToJson(app::Bar v){return "bar";};
}
```

If I overload PrintTo directly to these types it works correctly.

```
namespace app 
{
void PrintTo(const Foo& v, ::std::ostream* os) {return (*os) << utils::ToJson(v); }
void PrintTo(const Bar& v, ::std::ostream* os) {return (*os) << utils::ToJson(v); }
}
```

Since there are many classes that can be serialized and need to be tested I want PrintTo to be a generic one. So I ended up writing the following trait for detection if a type has ToJson overload

```
template <class, class = std::void_t<>>
struct is_json_convertible : std::false_type 
{};

template <class T>
struct is_json_convertible<
    T, std::void_t<decltype(utils::ToJson(std::declval<T>()))>>
    : std::true_type 
{};
```

And use it in PrintTo to enable it only for serializable types

```
namespace app 
{
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_json_convertible<T>::value>>
void PrintTo(const T& v, ::std::ostream* os)
{
    *os << utils::ToJson(v);
}
}
```

But I've got an ambiguous call to PrintTo error. (mine and defined in gtest)
Is it possible to overload a PrintTo with a template?

///// UPDATE

I've got right printing with ostream overloading instead

```
namespace app
{
template <class T,
          class = std::enable_if_t<is_json_convertible<T>::value>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& v)
{
    os << utils::ToJson(v);
    return os;
}
}
```

Comment: Is the declaration of your custom `PrintTo` (template) function in the the `.cpp` file of your test code, or in a separate header? If it is the former, it is possible that, at the point of overload resolution (internally in a GTEST source file) your custom overload _blueprint_ is not visible, and it will fall back to `template <typename T> void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os)  { ... }` of `gtest-printers.h`. As your custom overload it is a function template, it has likely not been instantiated for any set of template parameters, so no definition exists from the TU of your test. ...

Comment: _If_ so, you could try: A) Moving the function template declaration to a separate header, or B) (just for trying out my theory) explicitly instantiate the `PrintTo` function template in your test translation unit with, say, `Bar`, and see if the behaviour differs between JSON printout between `Foo` and `Bar` (via appropriate GTEST EXPECT/ASSERT failures).

Comment: @dfri thanks for your suggestions, they helped me find the bug in trait usage (it must be is_json_convertible<T>::value and not is_json_convertible<T>::type) resulting in the bad template being ignored now I've got an ambiguous call error

Comment: I thought that a compiler would prefer a template from the arguments template app::Foo, but it fails with an ambiguous error

Comment: Both template functions (yours and the `<typename T> void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os) { ... }` of `gtest-printers.h`) have the same _best viable function rank_, it just happens that one is found via unqualified name lookup (GTEST's) and another via ADL (your overload). If your overload was not a template function (as your  `void PrintTo(const Foo& v, ::std::ostream* os) { ... }` example) it would be a more viable function overload than an otherwise similarly good template function.

Comment: As you've sorted out yourself, GTEST does not supply a templated `operator<<`, so there will be no ambiguity with that approach. You will now actually be using GTEST's `<typename T> void PrintTo(const T& value, ::std::ostream* os) { ... }` function, which in turn will delegate (via `DefaultPrintTo(...)`) to your `operator<<` overload.

Comment: @dfri thanks for the help. Could you form the answer for future readers?

Comment: Happy to help. I can write something up later today.